# + symbol in 7th column in COBOL

Tags: cobol

Found code which uses the plus symbol(+) in the 7th position of COBOL/DB2 program. Any advice on this. Tried Google and found the symbols list as (-,*,/D), did not find any information on the symbol (+). Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You might get more specific help if you pointed us to the code you afe reading, but from what I found, compiler will ignore a `+`.

Comment: Thank you Amadan ....will ignore the symbol and read the code.... if any issues will share the sample.

Comment: what compiler are you using? column 7 is an indication area that can be used for a few different reasons. Without knowing that compiler you are using, it is impossible to say exactly what will happened. @Amadan is probably correct, but there is no way to say for sure

Comment: Without knowing your specific compiler, it's hard to say.  However, there are some language preprocessors that use a notation like that.  I suspect you would know if you were using one though.